# Как правильно создать сообщение CertificateVerify (TLS 1.3) с помощью OpenSSL на C/C++?

Tags: c++, openssl, rsa, tls, handshake

Пишу свою реализацию TLS 1.3 и застрял на сообщении server CertificateVerify - не могу понять как оно создаётся. При помощи openssl s_server получил образцы сообщений с одной сессии и вот пытаюсь добиться соответствия своей подписи с контентом референсного сообщения CertificateVerify. [Код и рабочие файлы](https://github.com/EugeneIceman/SignRSA) выложил в git (всего один cpp-файл на 216 строк, главное в main).

Помогите пожалуйста построить правильный колл-стек методов OpenSSL чтобы сгенерированная подпись соответствовала тому CertificateVerify, что выдал s_server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашёл в исходниках OpenSSL. Ответ [тут](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/ssl/statem/statem_lib.c#L272)